# Crear o integrar un sistema de ChangeLog en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

Normalmente utilizo la librería `android-change-log` para integrar un sistema de changelog en mis apps, pero creo que ya está muy obsoleto, no se corresponde con las directivas de Material Design.

¿Se puede forzar el cuadro de dialogo que usa, sea el de Material Design y no del arcaico `Holo Dialog`?

No integro el código ya que seria muy extenso, pero se puede vissualizar en su [GitHub aquí](https://github.com/koem/android-change-log/blob/master/src/sheetrock/panda/changelog/ChangeLog.java)

Podéis dejar en comentarios si conocéis otra librería o mejor solución.

Comment: Utilizando los [diálogos nativos de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) deberías tener el dialogo material para los dispositivos modernos, en el caso de los más viejos se va a ver con la estética propia de esa versión del OS, lo cual es preferible ya que se mantiene una experiencia consistente entre apps.